# jetty 6 continuations with glassfish?

Tags: glassfish, jetty, comet, continuations

Can Jetty 6 continuations be used in a glassfish container?  Can this be properly acheived to suspend requests as to not tie up the threadpool? Switching to a Jetty container is not an option. Using grizzly is also not an option (I need the comet support to work with activemq which uses continuations). I am stuck with glassfish v2.

So in other words, I'd like to use the jetty 6 continuation feature with all of its benefits within a different container.  Is this possible?

Comment: FWIW, I think the model is part of the Servlet 3.x specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

[ContinuationFilter](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/continuation/ContinuationFilter.html)